# Calculation Error for my Windows Form App?

Tags: winforms

I have a plus and minus button for my Windows Form App.

Clicking the Plus will add for example 3.2 to it and clicking the minus will decrease 3.2 from it.

The value is allowed to go negative.

Why is it that sometimes when I have clicked the Plus button a few times, and I start to decrease it by clicking the Minus button, when the value reaches 0, it does not display 0 but display a long string of numbers such as 8.88178419700

The code for my buttons are

```
private void btnMinus6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    total1 = total1 - 3.20;  
    lblTotal.Text = total1.ToString();
}
```

It works the same for the plus button, jus that it adds instead of decreases.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the data type of `total1`?

Comment: No, that's only a data type in Southern California.  Required reading: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: lol sorry. typo. i meant the data type is double.

Answer (score 1):

I would use System.Decimal as the data type (floating point numbers like System.Single and System.Double are approximations).

I would also confirm your control type is a System.Windows.Forms.Label control (or are you using a 3rd party control like from DevExpress...if so, there are many properties that might trip you up with respect to formatting)

i.e.:

```
private System.Decimal total1 = 0.0;

private void btnMinus6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{     
total1 -= 3.20;       
lblTotal.Text = total1.ToString(); 
}

private void btnPlus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{     
total1 += 3.20;       
lblTotal.Text = total1.ToString(); 
}
```

Comment: ya i am using the label control. may i know what is the difference between using the system.decimal against using double?